# Clear Entry text after moving to next page

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I want to clear the text of the password Entry after successfull login and move to the next page.

> SignInViewModel.cs

```
 public string EmailEntry { get; set; }
 public string PasswordEntry { get; set; }

        private async Task LogIn()
        {
            var user = _userService.LoginUser(EmailEntry);

            if (user == null)
            {
                await _pageService.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Invalid Credentials", "Ok");
                return;
            }

            if (user.Password != PasswordEntry)
            {
                await _pageService.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Invalid Credentials", "Ok");
                return;
            }

            PasswordEntry = "";
            await _pageService.PushAsync(new HomePage(user));

        }
```

> SignInPage.xaml

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" x:DataType="viewModels:SignInViewModel">
    <Entry Placeholder="Email" Text="{Binding EmailEntry}"/>
    <Entry Placeholder="Password" Text="{Binding PasswordEntry}" IsPassword="True"/>

    <Button 
        Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
        Text="Login" 
        Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" 
        CornerRadius="10"/>
</StackLayout>
```

> SignInPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class SignInPage
{
    public SignInPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new SignInViewModel(new PageService());

    }

    private SignInViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get => BindingContext as SignInViewModel;
        set => BindingContext = value;
    }
}
```

I want that when user login successfully and app goes to the next page then PasswordEntry will be initialized to Empty string

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewModel doesn't implement **INotifyPropertyChanged**, there is no way to inform the UI for a change.

You can use the following class as a base class for your SignInViewModel.

```
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

In SignInViewModel, Change your properties like this :

```
private string emailEntry;


    public string EmailEntry
    {
        get => emailEntry;
        set
        {
            emailEntry = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

private string passwordEntry;

    public string PasswordEntry
    {
        get => passwordEntry;
        set
        {
            passwordEntry = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

When you set your view model in the code-behind, you can keep things simple :

```
BindingContext = new SignInViewModel(new PageService());
```

Now the password should be empty when EmailEntry is set an empty string.